# Ticket to Ride New York transportation cards question

Tags: ticket-to-ride-new-york

My fiance and I are debating over a move he did that I believe is incorrect.  He chose to select transportation cards on his turn.  He picked up a red card and then we replaced the card from the deck to the play area.  It was a wild card (taxi).  He said that was the card he wanted and took it and put the red card back in its spot.  I say that is cheating because that was technically his second card choice and you cannot take a taxi as your second card. He says it is not cheating because he put the red card back.  Who is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At no point are players allowed to trade cards from their hand to the board.

The entirety of the rules for taking action on one's turn are in several short paragraphs in the rules. The only way to gain cards is to draw two cards blind from the deck, or take two non-taxi cards, or one of each, or take one taxi card.

There is no allowance for trading cards to the board, for putting the first card back if one prefers the replacement, or for taking the taxi card instead of the first choice.

Comment: Probably worth adding that if a user takes a blind choice from the deck and it's a Taxi (or wild card equivalent in other TTS games) that is does not count as both picks.  It's entirely possible to gain two 'wilds'  in a turn if taking blind from deck.  However, as you rightly say a player can't put a card back, take the wild and say they wanted it instead.  That is not allowed by the rules

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. The rules do not permit returning or exchanging the card in your hand to the draw stacks.